# normal operator over Field R

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, real-numbers, normal-operator

in class, we learned that over the complex numbers or the real numbers field, a normal operator is diagnosable, I got the idea why a normal operator is diagnosable over Complex field, but I didn't got the idea why a normal operator is diagonalizable over the real number field?

in the real number field, we can get that the characteristic polynomial is not a product of linear equations. why why normal operator is diagonalizable over the real number field ?

can we say that if a normal operator is diagonalizable over the real number field, then the operator is actually self-adjoint?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "diagnosable" you mean "diagonalizable".

It isn't.  For example, the $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix
$$ \pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\cr
            -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)}$$
is normal.  It has eigenvalues $\exp(\pm i \theta)$, and is thus not diagonalizable over the reals unless $\sin(\theta) = 0$.

Comment: On the other hand, it's normal, as it's diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: What does "normal" mean over an arbitrary field?

Comment: T : V ---> V is a linear operator over finite dimensional inner product space over Field F (some field ) and T is a normal operator . can I deduce that T is diagonalizable ? if yes why ?

Comment: I asked you to define "normal operator" over an arbitrary field.

Comment: I mean by" normal" operator a linear operator such that $T T^* = T^*T $, and our vector field is finite dimensional and  is over some artistry Field (not some specified field)? is that now more clear ?

Comment: by arbitrary field I mean the complex number field or the real numbers field

Comment: That's not arbitrary, it's just two possibilities.